# MouseDown event on FlowDocument scrolls down FlowDocumentScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I have a WPF windown in which I have a FlowDocumentScrollViewer, and a FlowDocument as its child. Inside the FlowDocument element, of course, I have grids, textboxes and such, and they all work fine, but whenever I click on them, the scroll bar is scrolled all the way down. The code is as such:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <FlowDocument x:Name="flowDoc" PagePadding="0">
        <Section>
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Grid x:Name="masterGrid" Height="1500">
                        <!--window structure here-->
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </BlockUIContainer>
        </Section>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

This behavior is not desired, but I also have no idea as to what is causing it. How do I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not adressing the cause (which is still unclear) but rather the problem itself, I managed to get it to stop scrolling all the way down by removing `FlowDocument` and `Section`, and switching `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` by `ScrollViewer`. For my needs, that was possible and enough.